# How to query database about Model from another App?

Tags: django, django-models, python-import

I have models like this:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    visable_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website_url = models.URLField()


class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class UserSubs(models.Model):
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription, to_field='visable_name')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field='username')
```

And I want to prepare simple ranking, so I came up with something like this: `Subscription.objects.annotate(total=models.Count('usersubs')).order_by('-total')`

The true problem is that I just discovered that my "simple ranking" should be in another App, where I can't even do `from FirstApp import models.Subscription`, becouse I get `ImportError`: `cannot import name Subscription`.

I actually have no idea how it has to be done.. Maybe should I give up from separate these two Apps?

Comment: `another App, where I can't even do from FirstApp import models.Subscription` -- Why not, what's the problem?

Comment: TBH.. It looks like bug for me.

Comment: No but what happens when you import the models of FirstApp in SecondApp ?  `from FirstApp.models import modelA, modelB`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by saying "simple ranking" should be in another app. What is "simple ranking" and why should it be separate?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I have two Apps actually, "Services" what is for manage Subscriptions, and "Rankings" what is mainly for list of most subscribed Subscriptions.

Comment: @Anto: I just get `ImportError` saying `cannot import name Subscription`.

Comment: @user2960307 and what does that have to do with this question?

Comment: @user2960307 ...  don't you think this might be the source of the issue here?  Could you consider updating your question (which seems to be about [python imports](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html) and not Django) with the relevant info?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: That's why I think it should be two separate Apps. Each of them do another things.

Answer (score 1):

I still don't really understand why you are trying to split these up, but it seems likely you have a circular dependency: your model files are both trying to import each other. You probably need to remove the import from one side: note that if you're importing simply to use as a reference in defining a ForeignKey, you can use a string: `models.ForeignKey('FirstApp.Subscription')` instead of the actual class.